# Memory overflow when using SQL Alchemy to load data into a SQL Server Database when looping in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy

I have written a python script that reads files one-by-one out of a blob storage account, reformat them into a data frame and then writes them to a SQL Server DB using SQL Alchemy for daily log files.

Each file is 300K - 900K records and each day can have up to 75 files. The problem comes in that the VM I am running the code on runs out of memory at right around file 50. I have tried everything I can think of to resolve this, using tracemalloc I have found that the file `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:585"` grows in memory with every loop while nothing else does. 
`gc.collect` is called at the end of every loop.

General pseudo code structure is:

```
For blob.name in blob:
     read in files
     log_df = clean files into df
     engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://creds/DB?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', fast_executemany=True)
     log_df.to_sql(table_name,engine,schema='dbo',if_exists='append', chunksize =1000, method=None, index=False) #chunk size of 1000 was found to be fastest      
     engine.dispose()
     del log_df
     gc.collect()
```

Any suggestions on how to release the memory after each run or a better approach would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: If you can't find and fix the memory leak (especially if it's inside SQL Alchemy) maybe break the process up into two Python scripts? The first is responsible for reading a single file out of blob storage into SQL; the second iterates over the blob storage account and invokes the first script for each file it finds.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.
I posted this issue in sqlalchemy GitHub. See below for link.
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5334

Issue appears to be when writing into nvarchar(max) columns. If sqlalchemy creates your table, it will auto set all columns to be nvarchar(max). Creating a table before without nvarchar(max) and then writing to it should fix this issue.